# DB2 and PL/1: Avoid redundancy by creating a reference to the appropriate cursor, work with it

Tags: db2, mainframe, zos

I'm writing a PL/1 subroutine that reads data from DB2. Depending on the input, it uses one of 3 cursors. These have to be opened, fetched, closed, etc. On every of these cursor-specific operations I have to specify its name. This leads to very redundant code, because the remaining operations are exactly the same for every case.

Is it possible to **create a reference**, to which I would assign the appropriate cursor? Then I could use this to perform the necessary tasks only once.

Because of safety-related restrictions, I'm not allowed to use dynamic (prepared) SQL.

And is there a **reference containing all commands** I can use in my EXEC SQL statements?

Thanks in advance
David

Answer (score 0):

> And is there a reference containing all commands I can use in my EXEC SQL statements?

IBM has [documentation for DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-12-zos-product-documentation), which contains an SQL reference for the product.

Comment: Thank you for this link. I found [a reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_statementsintro.htm) containing the DB2 statements which can be invoked out of a program (EXEC SQL). But apparently there is no command to create a reference (pointer) to a cursor :(.